# mySQL remove char(13) with trim

Tags: mysql

I have to remove leading CR and LF from a field in a SQL-Database. Since I only have to remove the leading characters I can not use REPLACE().

I thought using

```
UPDATE test
SET products_description = TRIM(LEADING CHAR(13) FROM products_description);
```

would do fine but it does NOT find any matching entries. Any idea why?

Yes, the first character is a char(13). Char(10) is the second.

Thx
Oliver

Comment: Do you want to remove leading space?

Comment: Every record contains leading `CR`? what is `char(13) and char(10)`? Do you want update all record?

Comment: No, not every record contains CR but I need to check all records. CR = CHAR(13), LF = CHAR(10).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with LTRIM function

```
UPDATE test
SET products_description = LTRIM(products_description);
```

Comment: I don't want to remove blancs. I have to remove CR and LF. As far as I know TRIM works only for blancs.

Answer (score 0):

```
update test SET products_description = SUBSTR(products_description,3);
```

for removing leading two character

Comment: not every record has the CR and LF at the beginning 8-(.